# Display a coloured SVG when hovering over a colourless SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using SVG's for social media icons, I am having trouble making it so whenever I hover over the default colourless SVG it displays a coloured version of it.
Here's the code for colourless SVG:

```html
<svg width="46" height="46" viewBox="0 0 46 46" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="23" cy="23" r="22" stroke="#E2E3E4" stroke-width="2"/>
<path opacity="0.3" d="M24 20V18.5C24 18.2348 24.1054 17.9804 24.2929 17.7929C24.4804 17.6054 24.7348 17.5 25 17.5H26V15H24C23.2044 15 22.4413 15.3161 21.8787 15.8787C21.3161 16.4413 21 17.2044 21 18V20H19V23H21V31H24V23H26L27 20H24Z" fill="#131821"/>
</svg>
```

Here's the code for coloured SVG:

```html
<svg width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d_74090_402)">
<circle cx="63" cy="43" r="23" fill="#4267B2"/>
</g>
<path d="M64 40V38.5C64 38.2348 64.1054 37.9804 64.2929 37.7929C64.4804 37.6054 64.7348 37.5 65 37.5H66V35H64C63.2044 35 62.4413 35.3161 61.8787 35.8787C61.3161 36.4413 61 37.2044 61 38V40H59V43H61V51H64V43H66L67 40H64Z" fill="white"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d_74090_402" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="20"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 0 0.0941176 0 0 0 0 0.129412 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Here's the CSS I am trying to use:

```
.facebook_icon{
position: absolute; 
left: 118px;
top: 50px;
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
background-image: url('./icons/facebook_normal.svg');
}
.facebook_icon:hover{

background-image: url('./icons/facebook_icon_hover.svg');
}
```

For some odd reason, the coloured SVG is not displaying itself correctly! Here's how it looks right now.

[image: Here's how it looks right now.]

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. However the viewBox you are using is too large for the icon. Please try `viewBox="40 20 46 46"`

Answer (score 0):

As commentented by **enxaneta**: you need to adjust the second icon's  `viewBox`.

You can easily visualize the current viewBox by adding a border (via CSS) to a svg.

You can quickly retrieve an appropriate viewBox using the native [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method.

```js
let bb = svgHoverFixed.getBBox();
let {x,y, width, height} = bb;
// get approriate viewBox (with some rounding)
let viewBoxCropped = [x, y, width, height].map(val => {
  return +val.toFixed(2)
}).join(' ');
svgHoverFixed.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxCropped);
console.log(viewBoxCropped)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="46" height="46" viewBox="0 0 46 46" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="23" cy="23" r="22" stroke="#E2E3E4" stroke-width="2"/>
<path opacity="0.3" d="M24 20V18.5C24 18.2348 24.1054 17.9804 24.2929 17.7929C24.4804 17.6054 24.7348 17.5 25 17.5H26V15H24C23.2044 15 22.4413 15.3161 21.8787 15.8787C21.3161 16.4413 21 17.2044 21 18V20H19V23H21V31H24V23H26L27 20H24Z" fill="#131821"/>
</svg>

<svg width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d_74090_402)">
<circle cx="63" cy="43" r="23" fill="#4267B2"/>
</g>
<path d="M64 40V38.5C64 38.2348 64.1054 37.9804 64.2929 37.7929C64.4804 37.6054 64.7348 37.5 65 37.5H66V35H64C63.2044 35 62.4413 35.3161 61.8787 35.8787C61.3161 36.4413 61 37.2044 61 38V40H59V43H61V51H64V43H66L67 40H64Z" fill="white"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d_74090_402" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="20"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 0 0.0941176 0 0 0 0 0.129412 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>

<svg id="svgHoverFixed" width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d_74090_402)">
<circle cx="63" cy="43" r="23" fill="#4267B2"/>
</g>
<path d="M64 40V38.5C64 38.2348 64.1054 37.9804 64.2929 37.7929C64.4804 37.6054 64.7348 37.5 65 37.5H66V35H64C63.2044 35 62.4413 35.3161 61.8787 35.8787C61.3161 36.4413 61 37.2044 61 38V40H59V43H61V51H64V43H66L67 40H64Z" fill="white"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d_74090_402" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="20"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 0 0.0941176 0 0 0 0 0.129412 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

To make your icons responsive you could use **relative units** like `em` or `rem` to scale them similarly to icon fonts:

```
.facebook_icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 1em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='46' height='46' viewBox='0 0 46 46' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle cx='23' cy='23' r='22' stroke='%23E2E3E4' stroke-width='2'/><path opacity='0.3' d='M24 20V18.5C24 18.2348 24.1054 17.9804 24.2929 17.7929C24.4804 17.6054 24.7348 17.5 25 17.5H26V15H24C23.2044 15 22.4413 15.3161 21.8787 15.8787C21.3161 16.4413 21 17.2044 21 18V20H19V23H21V31H24V23H26L27 20H24Z' fill='%23131821'/></svg>");
}
```

Unfortunately, your svg filter based drop-shadow will get cropped when used in a background-image.

But you can replace it with a [**CSS drop-shadow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) filter applied to the icon element.

```css
.icon-wrap {
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}


.facebook_icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 1em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='46' height='46' viewBox='0 0 46 46' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle cx='23' cy='23' r='22' stroke='%23E2E3E4' stroke-width='2'/><path opacity='0.3' d='M24 20V18.5C24 18.2348 24.1054 17.9804 24.2929 17.7929C24.4804 17.6054 24.7348 17.5 25 17.5H26V15H24C23.2044 15 22.4413 15.3161 21.8787 15.8787C21.3161 16.4413 21 17.2044 21 18V20H19V23H21V31H24V23H26L27 20H24Z' fill='%23131821'/></svg>");
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.facebook_icon:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='126' height='126' viewBox='40 20 46 46' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' overflow='visible'><g><circle cx='63' cy='43' r='23' fill='%234267B2'/></g><path d='M64 40V38.5C64 38.2348 64.1054 37.9804 64.2929 37.7929C64.4804 37.6054 64.7348 37.5 65 37.5H66V35H64C63.2044 35 62.4413 35.3161 61.8787 35.8787C61.3161 36.4413 61 37.2044 61 38V40H59V43H61V51H64V43H66L67 40H64Z' fill='white'/></svg>");
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
}
```

```html
<p class="icon-wrap"><span class="facebook_icon"></span>
  <span class="facebook_icon"></span>
  <span class="facebook_icon"></span>
</p>

<svg id="svgHoverFixed" width="126" height="126" viewBox="40 20 46 46" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d_74090_402)">
<circle cx="63" cy="43" r="23" fill="#4267B2"></circle>
</g>
<path d="M64 40V38.5C64 38.2348 64.1054 37.9804 64.2929 37.7929C64.4804 37.6054 64.7348 37.5 65 37.5H66V35H64C63.2044 35 62.4413 35.3161 61.8787 35.8787C61.3161 36.4413 61 37.2044 61 38V40H59V43H61V51H64V43H66L67 40H64Z" fill="white"></path>
<defs><filter id="filter0_d_74090_402" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dy="20"></feOffset><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 0 0.0941176 0 0 0 0 0.129412 0 0 0 0.3 0"></feColorMatrix><feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402"></feBlend><feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_74090_402" result="shape"></feBlend></filter></defs>
</svg>
```

#### Further reading:

["6 Common SVG Fails (and How to Fix Them)"](https://css-tricks.com/6-common-svg-fails-and-how-to-fix-them/#aa-1-the-viewbox-values)